# How to turn on SalesForce intellisense in MavensMate

Tags: mavensmate

I have the latest update from MavensMate and I'm unable to see intellisense, how to turn on that feature?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I do remember there is a way to download the project data in MavensMate. But still, it doesn't work very well for me as an intellisense. To enable that, I would recommend you consider adding some more sublime plugins. Consider the following two: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/haoide and https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Visualforce